# Watching part of a page (no ID) using urlwatch

Tags: url, monitor

I use urlwatch to watch for changes in websites. 
On some sites I just want to overwatch a part of the site.

**Example:**
On http://www.wikifolio.com/de/DAXEN020 I just want to get notified when the is a change in the "Trade" section.

Using "Page Monitor" in Chrome I get this when I watch for changes in this part

```
<td class="js-virtual-order-status-text virtual-order-overview-status">
Ausgeführt
<br>
<span class="smalldatetime">20.11.2015&nbsp;17:27</span>
</td>"
```

How can I get this filter into urlwatch?

Thanks in advance